# Run Goroutines on separate processes (multiprocessing)

Tags: go, multiprocessing, goroutine

I currently have a MQTT code that can subscribe to a topic, print out the messages received, then publish further instructions to a new topic. The **subscribing/printing** is completed in one Goroutine, and the **publishing** is done in another Goroutine. Here is my code:

```
var wg, pg sync.WaitGroup
// All messages are handled here - printing published messages and publishing new messages
var f MQTT.MessageHandler = func(client MQTT.Client, msg MQTT.Message) {

wg.Add(1)
pg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", msg.Payload())
        //fmt.Println(os.Getpid())
    }()
go func(){
    defer pg.Done()
    message := ""
    //Changing configurations
    if strings.Contains(string(msg.Payload()), "arduinoLED") == true {
        message = fmt.Sprintf("change configuration")
    }
    if  strings.Contains(string(msg.Payload()), "NAME CHANGED") == true{
        message = fmt.Sprintf("change back")
    }
    // Publish further instructions to "sensor/instruction"
    token := client.Publish("sensor/instruction", 0, false, message)
    //fmt.Println(os.Getpid())
    token.Wait()

}()
}

func main() {

    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    opts := MQTT.NewClientOptions().AddBroker("tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883")

    opts.SetDefaultPublishHandler(f)
    // Topic to subscribe to for sensor data
    topic := "sensor/data"

    opts.OnConnect = func(c MQTT.Client) {
        if token := c.Subscribe(topic, 0, f); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
            panic(token.Error())
        }
    }
    // Creating new client
    client := MQTT.NewClient(opts)
    if token := client.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        panic(token.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Connected to server\n")
    }
    wg.Wait()
    pg.Wait()
    <-c
}
```

The commented out `os.Getpid()` line is to check which process I am running that Goroutine on. Right now they both display the same number (which means both are running on the same process?).

**My question is:** How can I run the two Goroutines on **separate processes**? Is there a way?

**Edit:** If this cannot be done, I want to write this code using **channels**. Here is the code I have for that:

```
var f MQTT.MessageHandler = func(client MQTT.Client, msg MQTT.Message) {
    sensorData := make(chan []byte)
wg.Add(1)
pg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        //fmt.Printf("%s\n", msg.Payload())
        sensorData <- string(msg.Payload())
        fmt.Println(<-sensorData) //currently not printing anything
    }()
go func(){
    defer pg.Done()
    message := ""
    //Changing configurations
    if strings.Contains(<-sensorData, "arduinoLED") == true{
        message = fmt.Sprintf("change configuration")
    }
    if strings.Contains(<-sensorData, "NAME CHANGED") == true{
        message = fmt.Sprintf("change back")
    }
    // Publish further instructions to "sensor/instruction"
    token := client.Publish("sensor/instruction", 0, false, message)
    token.Wait()

}()

}
```

However, I am not able to print out any data using channels. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, you can't do that. Why do you think you need a separate process?

Comment: @JimB To avoid having the goroutines access the same memory by accident. I can use channels to overcome this correct? I'll post the updated code I have using channels, but I'm unable to change configurations using this method.

Comment: Channels aren't an IPC mechanism. If you need a separate process, you need to exec it yourself and sue something else for IPC.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "exec it yourself"? I thought it wasn't possible to run the two Goroutines on separate processes?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You might be coming from Python, right? ;-)

It has the module named
[`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)
in its stdlib, and this might well explain why you have used
this name in the title of your question and why you apparently
are having trouble interpreting what @JimB meant by saying

> If you need a separate process, you need to exec it yourself

#### "Multiprocessing" in Python

The thing is, Python's `multiprocessing` is a quite high-level
thing which hides under its hood a whole lot of stuff.
When you spawn a `multiprocessing.Process` and make it run
a function, what really happens is this:

1. The Python interpreter creates another operating system's
   process (using
   [`fork(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) on Unix-like systems
   or [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425) on Windows) and arranges
   for it to execute a Python interpter, too.

   The crucial point is that you will now have two processes
   running two Python interpters.
2. It is arranged for that Python interpterer in the
   child process to have a way to communicate with the Python
   interpreter in the parent process.

   This "communication link" *necessarily* involves some form
   of [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) @JimB referred to.
   There is simply no other way to communicate data and actions
   between *separate* processes exactly because a commodity
   contemporary OS provides strict process separation.
3. When you [exchange Python objects between the processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes), the two communicating Python
   interpreters *serialize* and *deserialize* them behind your back
   before sending them over their IPC link and after receiving
   them from there, correspondingly.
   This is implemented using the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module.

#### Back to Go

Go does not have any direct solution which would closely
match Python's `multiprocessing`, and I really doubt it could
have been sensibly implemented.

The chief reason for this mostly stems from the fact Go
is quite more lower level than Python, and hence it does not
have the Python's luxury of making sheer assumptions about
the types of values it manages, and it also strives to have
as few hidden costs in its constructs as possible.

Go also strives to steer clear of "framework-style" approaches
to solve problems, and use "library-style" solutions when
possible. (A good rundown of the "framework vs library"
is given, for instance, [here](https://medium.com/iquii/applications-vs-frameworks-vs-libraries-c1f1a6122711).)
Go has everything in its standard library to implement
something akin to Python's `multiprocessing` but there is no
ready-made frakework-y solution for this.

So what you could do for this is to roll along these lines:

1. Use `os/exec` to run another copy of your own process.

   - Make sure the spawned process "knows" it's started
     in the special "slave" mode—to act accordingly.
   - Use any form of IPC to communicate with the new process.
     Exchanging data via the [standard I/O streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)
     of the child process is supposedly
     the simplest way to roll (except when you need to exchange
     opened files but this is a harder topic, so let's not digress).
2. Use any suitable package in the [`encoding/` hierarchy](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#section-directories) — such as `binary`, `gob`, `xml` — to serialize
   and deserialize data when exchanging.

   The "go-to" solution is supposedly [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob)
   but [`encoding/json` will also do just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68641535/720999).
3. Invent and implement a simple protocol to tell the
   child process what to do, and with which data,
   and how to communicate the results back to master.

#### Does it really worth the trouble?

I would say that no, it doesn't—for a number of reasons:

- Go has nothing like the dreaded [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock),
  so there's no need to sidestep it to achieve real parallelism
  when it is naturally possible.
- Memory safety is all in your hands, and achieving it is
  not really that hard when you dutifully obey the principle
  that *what is sent over a channel is now **owned by
  the receiver.*** In other words, sending values over a channel
  is also the transfer of ownership of those values.
- The Go toolchain has integrated race detector, so you
  may run your test suite with the `-race` flag and create evaluation
  builds of your program using `go build -race` for the same
  purpose: when a program instrumented in such a way runs,
  the race detector crashes it as soon as it detects any
  unsynchronized read/write memory access.
  The printout resulting from that crash includes
  explanatory messages on what, *and where* went wrong,
  with stack traces.
- IPC is slow, so the gains may well be offset by the losses.

All-in-all, I see no real reason to separate processes unless
you're writing something like an e-mail processing server
where this concept comes naturally.

Comment: BTW it may be interesting to consider that Go once had an experimental [`netchan`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/exp/old/netchan) package that [was discontinued](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/154020/303695).

Comment: I'm coming from Python, and this answer was very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: 3 years later, and this answer made everything so easy to understand :) ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Channel is used for communicating between goroutines, you shouldn't use it in same goroutine like this code:

```
sensorData <- string(msg.Payload())
fmt.Println(<-sensorData) //currently not printing anything
```

If you like to test printing by channel, you can use buffered channel in same goroutine to avoid blocking, like this:

```
sensorData := make(chan []byte, 1)
```

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Ok there are two things going on here.
When you use goroutines the go runtime will schedule them according to the needs of your program. In your example program there is no need to schedule the goroutines on different processes so the go runtime doesn't use separate processes.

If you keep sending and receiving more events concurrently then eventually the go runtime might use separate processes.

The point of the abstraction of goroutines is that you as a developer don't have to worry about processes. Also the implementation of goroutines is a lot more lightweight than processes or even threads.

All that being said the solution to your problem doesn't involve processes.

If you pass data by value instead of by reference go will copy that value to prevent two parts of your program editing the same memory.

https://go.dev/tour/methods/4

Assuming you use the eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang library the message is a struct with the payload being a byte array (https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/blob/master/message.go#L41)

To prevent editing the payload you can make a copy of it or cast it to a string.

This should be less complex and better to understand than spawning an additional process.