# Reuse socket connection between client and server

Tags: python, sockets, go

I have a client written in python communicate with a server written in Go via TCP Socket. Currently, I create a new socket object and then connect to Go server every time. More specifically, suppose my go server listens on `localhost:4040`, whenever I connect to from python server I has a different source address `(localhost:6379, 6378, ...)` . I wonder if there is a way to leverage on old connections (like a connection pool) rather than creating the new one every time. If so, how to determine the connection has finished and became idle , do I need an extra ACK message for that? Thanks.

Comment: @kostix made a good answer about that in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68641535/4466350

Comment: @mh-cbon thanks for your reply but it isn't my question, I do have a protocol for message . Currently I close the connection as soon as the message is handled on TCP server so the client can't reuse that connection.

Comment: you mean like automagically re use the conns without changing your implementations ?

Comment: For example: in case I create a connection A from `localhost:6789` to Go server 'localhost:4040`, the server start receiving the message and after handling completely, the server doesn't close the connection A, so the connection A still hang up and can be reused from client.  My concern is whether the connection A is closed by timeout (or some sort)? And if I initially create 10 connections to server, how can I pick one of them which is idle to send message? how to determine the connection is idle?

Comment: both sides should implement some sort of pooling, and you use the protocol layer to figure out which is idling, which is in-use. You already made the difficult part about the protocol. I suppose it contains a way to indicate the end of one communication (that might includes multiple exchanges), start there.

Comment: Actually, I just write data to connection (for example 5 bytes) from client, and on server I read (10 bytes), It means I read all 5 bytes and start to decode message and handle it. Now every time I create a new connection so it isn't a problem if I read beyond the size of message. But in case I reuse that connection and continue to write another 5-byte message, is it possible that I will read whole 10 bytes and lead to wrong message decoding?