# What's the proper way to dynamically load (custom) DLLs at runtime in Golang?

Tags: windows, go, winapi, dll

I know that you can easily grab system DLLs by using `LoadDLL()`/`NewLazyDLL()`, finding the need Proc using `FindProc()`

But this seems to fail If I'm attempting to load my own DLLs that are made in Go,
Example

This is the main EXE that attempts to load the DLL

```golang
package main
import (
"log"
"golang.org/x/sys/windows" )

func main(){
  mod,err  := windows.LoadDLL("testdll.dll")
  if err!=nil{log.Fatal(err)}
  proc,err := mod.FindProc("FI")
  if err!=nil{log.Fatal(err)}
  proc.Call()
}
```

`built using: $ GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build myLoader.go`

And this is the DLL created in Go

```golang
package main
import (
"fmt"
)
import "C"

//export FI
func FI() int {
  fmt.Println("Works")
  return 7
}
func main(){}
```

`built using: $ CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -buildmode=c-shared -o testdll.dll testdll.go`

upon execution, it crashes and gives me one of those massive stack traces, with the last line pointing to `proc.Call()`

Go version is 1.18.1

Comment: What's the error message at the top of the crash?

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order). TL;DR: Do not use relative paths, like, ever. Construct a fully-qualified path name. Always.

Comment: @IInspectable, quite possibly a spot-on but I'd argue that `testdll.dll` is a name with the high probability for a clash ;-)

Comment: @kostix `bad sweepgen in refill` 
Here is the complete stack trace:
https://pastebin.com/LzLtJgKZ

Comment: @IInspectable I have tried with both ./DLLname and C:\full\path\to\dll and it still broken.
I think this is most likely an issue with having two go runtimes.

Comment: That's very interesting because that's an internal runtime error generated by the memory manager: <https://go.dev/src/runtime/mcache.go#L156>

Comment: Are you sure you're not having a case where a Go program loads a DLL compiled from Go code (or loads another DLL compiled from Go code) as [explained here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50304#issuecomment-999302888)?

Comment: @kostix well Yes, the DLL *is* made from Go, but so is the Loader

Comment: It seems that it's impossible according to that thread.

Comment: Yeah, if you need a loadable module either use [`plugin`](https://pkg.go.dev/plugin) or hook your external code in via some sort of IPC—for instance, make it an EXE, run it as an external process and communicate with it via its standard I/O streams using some agreed-upon protocol (using `encoding/gob` or `encoding/json` or whatnot); [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51091526/720999).

Comment: @Recar, be sure to read the comment thread. Basically this problem cannot be solved "as is".